# googletrans doesn't translate the numbers

Tags: python, google-translate, language-translation, googletrans

The translator works fine for the phrases and word but doesn't convert the English numbers into other languages

if I did this

```
nep= translator.translate('12', dest='nepali')
print(nep.text)
```

the output will be :

```
 12
```

but it should be:

```
 १२
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hindu-Arabic counting system (google this) is not English, it is used by many languages, and has existed well before the English language did. I would think that translate would know this. What you need to do is translate the Hindu-Arabic numbers into English words first, then you can translate them.

```
>> pip install num2words
```

```
import num2words
print(num2words.num2words(5))
print(num2words.num2words(57))
```